Estimates for incomplete Gamma functions

I want to show that
$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{n}} \exp(-s^4)s^{n+1} ds - \int_{\sqrt{n}}^{\infty} \exp(-s^4)s^{n+1} ds \geq 0\, \quad \text{for all }n\in\mathbb{N}.$$

These integrals can in fact be written as upper and lower incomplete gamma functions:
$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{n}} \exp(-s^4)s^{n+1} ds = \frac{1}{4} \gamma\left(\frac{n+2}{4},n^2\right)$$
and
$$\int_{\sqrt{n}}^{\infty} \exp(-s^4)s^{n+1} ds = \frac{1}{4} \Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}{4},n^2\right)$$
So essentially, I want to prove
$$\gamma\left(\frac{n+2}{4},n^2\right)\geq\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}{4},n^2\right)\quad \text{for all }n\in\mathbb{N},$$
but I could not find anything useful on this. Any suggestions?
Thanks already,
Nils

This is equivalent to $\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}{4}\right)\ge 2\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}{4},n^2\right)$

https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11  could be useful

Let $n\ge 1$ be a real number. We split into two cases.
Case 1. $1 \le n < 2$
We have
\begin{align*}
 \int_0^{\sqrt{n}} \exp(-s^4)s^{n+1} \,\mathrm{d}s
 &\ge \int_0^1 \exp(-s^4)s^{n+1} \,\mathrm{d}s\\
 &\ge \int_0^1 \exp(-s^4)s^{3} \,\mathrm{d}s\\
 &= \frac14 - \frac14 \mathrm{e}^{-1}.
\end{align*}
Also, we have
\begin{align*}
 \int_{\sqrt{n}}^\infty \exp(-s^4)s^{n+1} \,\mathrm{d}s
 &\le \int_1^\infty \exp(-s^4)s^{n+1} \,\mathrm{d}s\\
 &\le \int_1^\infty \exp(-s^4)s^{3} \,\mathrm{d}s\\
 &= \frac14 \mathrm{e}^{-1}.
\end{align*}
Since $\frac14 \mathrm{e}^{-1} < \frac14 - \frac14 \mathrm{e}^{-1}$, the desired inequality is true.
Case 2. $n\ge 2$
We have
\begin{align*}
 \int_{\sqrt{n}}^{\infty} \exp(-s^4)s^{n+1} \,\mathrm{d}s
 &= \int_{n^2}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{4}x^{n/4 - 1/2}\, \mathrm{d} x\\
 &= \int_{n^2}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x/2}}{4}\mathrm{e}^{-x/2}x^{n/4 - 1/2}\, \mathrm{d} x\\
 &\le \int_{n^2}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x/2}}{4}\, \mathrm{d} x\\
 &= \frac12\mathrm{e}^{-n^2/2}\\
 &\le \frac12\mathrm{e}^{-2}
\end{align*}
where we use $\mathrm{e}^{-x/2}x^{n/4 - 1/2} \le 1$ for all $x \ge n^2$ (use derivative).
Also, we have
\begin{align*}
 \int_0^{\sqrt{n}} \exp(-s^4)s^{n+1} \,\mathrm{d}s
 &= \int_0^{n^2} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{4}x^{n/4 - 1/2}\, \mathrm{d} x\\
 &\ge \int_1^{n^2} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{4}x^{n/4 - 1/2}\, \mathrm{d} x\\
 &\ge \int_1^{n^2} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{4}\, \mathrm{d} x\\
 &\ge \int_1^{4} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{4}\, \mathrm{d} x\\
 &= \frac14 \mathrm{e}^{-1} - \frac14 \mathrm{e}^{-4}.
\end{align*}
Since $\frac12\mathrm{e}^{-2} < \frac14 \mathrm{e}^{-1} - \frac14 \mathrm{e}^{-4}$, the desired inequality is true.
We are done.

Thank you very much! This works well.

@Nils You are welcome.

Substitute $x=s^4$. Then $s=x^{1/4}, \text{d}s = \frac14x^{-3/4}\text{ d}x$. The integrand then takes the form
$$
\exp(-s^4)s^{n+1}\text{ d}s=\exp(-x)x^{\frac{n+1}4-\frac34}\text{ d}x=x^{\frac{n+2}4-1}e^{-x}\text{ d}x
$$
which is the integrand for $\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}4\right)$. By adding $\int_0^{n^2}x^{\frac{n+2}4-1}e^{-x}\text{ d}x$ to both sides, the inequality becomes
$$
\int_0^{\infty}x^{\frac{n-2}4}e^{-x}\text{ d}x\ge2\int_{n^2}^\infty x^{\frac{n-2}4}e^{-x}\text{ d}x
$$
or $\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}4\right)\ge2\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}4,n^2\right)$ as @Zima pointed out.
If you test this inequality for a couple of $n$, you'll see that the right-hand side is often much much smaller than the left. Furthermore, $\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}4, n^2\right)$ actually decreases with $n$ (extremely rapidly!) while $\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}4\right)$ increases:



$n$
$\Gamma(\frac{n+2}4)$
$2\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}4,n^2\right)$




1
1.22542
0.637266


2
1
0.0366313


3
0.906402
0.00043854


4
0.886227
9.27608*10^-7


5
0.919063
3.19771*10^-10


6
1
1.71645*10^-14


7
1.133
1.39425*10^-19


8
1.32934
1.68109*10^-25


9
1.60836
2.96752*10^-32


10
2
7.59044*10^-40



This means that the inequality is not tight at all, and we can afford to be very lax with our bounds.
Here's one approach: I'll try to simplify the integration by bounding the right-hand side with an exponential:
$$
x^{\frac{n-2}4} \le e^{ax}
$$
for where $a < 1$ is some constant that might change with $n$. Then, the right-hand side can be bounded as
$$\begin{aligned}
2\int_{n^2}^\infty x^{\frac{n-2}4}e^{-x}\text{ d}x &\le 2\int_{n^2}^\infty e^{-(1-a)x}\text{ d}x = \frac{2e^{-(1-a)n^2}}{1-a}
\end{aligned}$$
The defining inequality for $a$ can be rearranged as
$$ax \ge \ln\left(x^{\frac{n-2}4}\right) = \frac{n-2}4\ln x$$
Thus, $a$ should satisfy
$$1\ge a\ge \frac{n-2}4\frac{\ln x}x$$
for all $x\ge n^2$. Since $\frac{\ln x}x$ is decreasing for $x>e$, this is equivalent to requiring
$$1\ge a\ge \frac{n-2}4\frac{\ln\left(n^2\right)}{n^2} = \frac{(n-2)\ln n}{2n^2}$$
At this stage, it's fairly clear that there are many choices for $a$, since the last expression doesn't even exceed $0.1$: it's global maximum for $n\ge1$ is $0.0997059$ near $n=6.3$. To be concrete, let's pick $a=1/2$. This clearly satisfies the required bound since
$$\ln n \le n-1 \implies \ln n < n \implies \frac12 > \frac{n\ln n}{2n^2}>\frac{(n-2)\ln n}{2n^2}$$
Thus,
$$\begin{aligned}
2\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}4,n^2\right) = 2\int_{n^2}^\infty x^{\frac{n-2}4}e^{-x}\text{ d}x \le \frac{2e^{-(1-a)n^2}}{1-a} = 4e^{-n^2/2}
\end{aligned}$$
is a really small number which decreases faster-than-exponentially! Since $\Gamma(\frac{n+2}4)$ increases for large $n$ and never dips below $\Gamma\left(\frac32\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\approx0.886$, we have
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}4\right)\ge\Gamma\left(\frac32\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\approx0.886\ge4e^{-2}\approx0.541\ge4e^{-n^2/2}\ge2\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}4,n^2\right)$$
for $n\ge2$. The inequality is a little too weak for the $n=1$ case, but you can check that case directly: $\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)\approx1.225>2\Gamma\left(\frac34,1\right)\approx0.637$.
